# Lightweight linux distro for web developer with slow computer?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lightweight GUI Linux distribution for really old computer](https://superuser.com/questions/73912/lightweight-gui-linux-distribution-for-really-old-computer)

I temporarily have to use a slow computer:

- 1.2 Ghz P3
- 384 MB RAM

On my usual computer, I use Ubuntu with Quanta+. Windows XP seems so slow. So I'm searching for a linux distro, with these requirements:

- good package support
- good performance - when using only firefox and IDE
- easily installable, free, good IDE supporting remote(FTP) web(PHP) development

Comment: this is prolly going to get closed, but give vectorlinux light a poke - i was running it on a PIII 450

Comment: try [XUbuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/). it is specifically designed for low-spec comps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to install Ubuntu Minimal

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

and then install very lightweight window manager like Openbox, E17 etc.

No, LXDE, XFCE and of course no GNOME and KDE.

After it, you would use **nginx** as a lightweight web server.
And code through **VIM**

Answer (score 2):

[Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) is fast, light-weight, and compatible with Debian-based packages.  It uses a DSL-specific package manager by default, but you can get a Debian-compatible one as well.  It runs extremely well on older machines, and the default distribution is only 50 MB (!) and it has more then enough stuff to get you started.  You can then just add whichever IDE you want, as well as the web browser you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you search these sites you will find something you can use.
Distro Watch
http://distrowatch.com/
live cd list [for the whole linux list-(maybe not)]
http://www.livecdlist.com/
linux freedom [good reviews of 64 linux OS's]
http://linuxfreedom.com/Distros/
slax 6 - good support[see linux freedom]
http://www.slax.org/
AUSTRUMI (Austrum Latvijas Linukss) is a business card size (the current size is 93MB)
install to disk not memory and poss replace its verson of firefox.[linux freedom]a bit tricky setting lang-i had to remember the places of icons (written in latvin) to change to english-not to hard.
http://cyti.latgola.lv/ruuni/
tinycore 11mb
http://tinycorelinux.com
hope you find something suitable